Are bitcoin-related tax questions considered offtopic?
For example, would the question "Does the IRS bitcoin policy double-tax miners?" be considered off-topic and should it be posted instead on money.stackexchange?

related: How do we handle legal advice / questions on legality?

It really concerns the Bitcoin niche a lot more than just finance. You'd need to have experience with Bitcoin to know the answer to this question, you wouldn't have to be a financial pro. The people at money.SE wouldn't know the answer to the question unless they know what Bitcoin is or the question explains it well.

I think this goes for bitcoin-related anything, at least for the foreseeable future, as not many professionals have the fundamental understanding of BC or crypto currencies in general to be able to help. That said, folks should try their best to explain their situation to finance professionals, but that doesn't make it off-topic here.
